# "Configuration system failed to initialize" when accessing settings.settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, settings

Ever since deleting the original settings.settings file I have had endless problems getting the settings to function. I receive the "Configuration system failed to initialize" error on the get or set methods. Any ideas? thanks.

```
    public static Settings Default {
        get {
            return defaultInstance;
        }
    }

    [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("Keywords.log")]
    public string KeywordsLog {
        get {
            return ((string)(this["KeywordsLog"]));
        }
        set {
            this["KeywordsLog"] = value;
        }
    }
```

Problem is located in Settings.Designer.cs

Adrian Banks, I'm afraid I don't know how to further debug? It already breaks on the error. The header of the box given is "ConfigurationErrorsException" if that helps in any way.

**I apologize, I did not realize you could see further details in VS.**

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException was unhandled
  Message="Configuration system failed to initialize"
  Source="System.Configuration"
  BareMessage="Configuration system failed to initialize"
  Line=0
  StackTrace:
       at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
       at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.PrepareClientConfigSystem(String sectionName)
       at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.RefreshConfig(String sectionName)
       at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(String sectionName)
       at System.Configuration.ClientSettingsStore.ReadSettings(String sectionName, Boolean isUserScoped)
       at System.Configuration.LocalFileSettingsProvider.GetPropertyValues(SettingsContext context, SettingsPropertyCollection properties)
       at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.GetPropertiesFromProvider(SettingsProvider provider)
       at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.GetPropertyValueByName(String propertyName)
       at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.get_Item(String propertyName)
       at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.GetPropertyValue(String propertyName)
       at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.get_Item(String propertyName)
       at READOO.Properties.Settings.get_KeywordsLog() in C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\READOO\READOO\Properties\Settings.Designer.cs:line 31
       at READOO.SettingsWindow..ctor() in C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\READOO\READOO\SettingsWindow.cs:line 19
       at READOO.WelcomeWindow.Settings_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\READOO\READOO\WelcomeWindow.cs:line 23
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at READOO.Program.Main() in C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\READOO\READOO\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
       Message="Section or group name 'READOO.Properties.Settings' is already defined. This can not be defined multiple times. (C:\\Users\\USER\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\\READOO\\READOO\\bin\\Debug\\READOO.exe.config line 6)"
       Source="System.Configuration"
       BareMessage="Section or group name 'READOO.Properties.Settings' is already defined. This can not be defined multiple times."
       Filename="C:\\Users\\USER\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\\READOO\\READOO\\bin\\Debug\\READOO.exe.config"
       Line=6
       StackTrace:
            at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
            at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
            at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
       InnerException:
```

@ joan -> chill.

Comment: Odd, where is this error occurring (eg runtime, vs designer), and have you got any steps to reproduce. As I just tried deleting the settings file but keeping the the class that was generated and it works fine.

Comment: Can you debug the error and break where the "Configuration system failed to initialize" exception occurs? If so, does the inner exception have any further info as to what is causing the problem?

Comment: Sounds like something could be failing to de-serialize, as Adrian, check for inner exceptions, or any other details that might contain a full error message.

Comment: Is it really such an advanced concept that when you ask a question about an exception, that you should **post the complete exception**?

Comment: @Nona: I apologize. It never occurred to me that someone might receive an exception and treat it as something opaque, with just a name and message. It is literally the case than I don't understand how people learn .NET these days (the "_I_ don't understand" part is clearly _my_ fault).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This would be your clue:

> Section or group name 'READOO.Properties.Settings' is already defined. This can not be defined multiple times. (C:\Users\Dylan\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\READOO\READOO\bin\Debug\READOO.exe.config line 6)

You probably have 2 `<section name="READOO.Properties.Settings">` elements in your `<configSections>` definition within that config file.

The duplicate entry is most likely at line 6 in said config file.

Answer (score 6):

It happened to me too. The solution was to delete everything in Users\yourUserName\AppData\Local\YourAppName.

It seems when some setting was saved as User scope of setting and then you turned (in Settings.settings designer) it to be Application scope of setting something got messed up and VS doesn't know where to take the setting value from.

Now, if you just add some setting as User scope setting and then turn it to be Application scope setting (without changing and saving it programmatically) - everything goes OK.
But if you save the setting with Properties.Settings.Default.Save() and then try to turn it to the Application scope it start to cause the problem.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I had set some settings to user scope by accident.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is 3 years old but the problem never gets old .. in case 
someone stumbles upon this ..

I had the same issue when I copied a configuration section from 
one project into another project's app.config and failed to copy 
the full namespace ..

```
<membership>
    <providers> ..
```

instead of

```
 <system.web>
   <membership>
       <providers> ..
```

Make sure you use the full set.